# How to use WebMarkupMin.MsAjax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, minify

I'm trying to minify using WebMarkupMin.MsAjax in a standard ASP.NET MVC4 project, but I don't understand how

I dug around on different sites and could not find the answer, and the documentation simply does not open. Please, help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.